# Add Series to DataFrame with additional index values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, series

I have a DataFrame which looks like this:

```
  Value
1 23
2 12
3 4
```

And a Series which looks like this:

```
1 24
2 12
4 34
```

Is there a way to add the Series to the DataFrame to obtain a result which looks like this:

```
  Value New
1 23    24
2 12    12
3 4     0
4 0     34
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [`concat(..., axis=1)`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) and [`.fillna()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22/generated/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([23,12,4], columns=["Value"], index=[1,2,3])
s = pd.Series([24,12,34],index=[1,2,4], name="New")

df = pd.concat([df,s],axis=1)
print(df)

df = df.fillna(0)  # or df.fillna(0, inplace=True)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
   Value   New
1   23.0  24.0
2   12.0  12.0
3    4.0   NaN
4    NaN  34.0

# If replacing NaNs with 0:

   Value   New
1   23.0  24.0
2   12.0  12.0
3    4.0   NaN
4    NaN  34.0
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use join between a series and a dataframe:

```
my_df.join(my_series, how='outer').fillna(0)
```

Example:

```
>>> df
   Value
1     23
2     12
3      4
>>> s
0
1    24
2    12
4    34

>>> type(df)
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>

>>> type(s)
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>

>>> df.join(s, how='outer').fillna(0)

   Value     1
1   23.0  24.0
2   12.0  12.0
3    4.0   0.0
4    0.0  34.0
```